Question easily answered on one's own?
I don't want to look too grumpy, but I'd say that a question like «How can I say "what's your name?” in Italian?» does not show even a modicum of attempt to find an answer on one's own. A sentence like this can be found in any elementary phrasebook, online and elsewhere. But, in my attempt to minimise grumpiness, I'd rather have a second (and third and...) opinion.

I agree. This site is not a free translation service.

That's certainly a troubling question, but more troubling is the fact that it had a score of 5 at time of this comment. Use your downvotes, everyone!

In un momento di deficit di domande, come si suol dire, tutto fa brodo.

You don't look grumpy, DaG. We've discussed it before here and here and unequivocally decided that such questions are off-topic.
I edited also our "on-topic" help page, clarifying the issue once and for all. Please feel free to edit or suggest other edits to that page.
